# linkbutton within repeater within updatepanel to spawn new window using RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, updatepanel, postback, repeater, registerclientscriptblock

I've a weird situation.

I have a Repeater within an UpdatePanel. The repeater has a linkbutton which spawns a new window - or rather, which should spawn a new window. When the repeater was outside of the UpdatePanel it worked fine; now it doesn't.

I've tried making the repeater an AsyncPostBack trigger, with no luck:

```
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rptEmployees" />
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgClear" />
                </Triggers>
```

I've tried making the Linkbutton an AsyncPBtrigger on ItemDataBound, with no luck:

```
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnVcard");
          sm1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
```

When I make the Linkbutton a PostBackTrigger, the popup appears once. Any subsequent time I hit one of the linkbuttons (until I do a hard refresh) no popup appears, although the ItemCommand of the Repeater is always hit:

```
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "", "<script>var" +
                                                                  @"  win=window.open('vCard.aspx',null,'width=50,height=50," +
                                                                  @"top=100,left=100','true');</script>", false);
```

Finally, here's my ItemTemplate:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
                            <!--For IE9 there can be no whitespace -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="140"><strong><%# Eval("DisplayName") %></strong><asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HFname" Value='<%# Eval("SamAccountName") %>'/></td>
                                <td width="100"><%# Eval("Office") %></td>
                                <td width="120"><%# Eval("WorkPhone") %></td>
                                <td width="120"><%# Eval("MobilePhone") %></td>
                                <td width="300" style="text-align: left"><a href="mailto:<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>"><%# Eval("EmailAddress") %></a></td>
                                <td><div class="button"><asp:LinkButton CommandName="vCard" runat="server" ID="lbtnVcard" Text="vCard" CssClass="button"/></div></td>
                            </tr>


                        </ItemTemplate>
```

Any clues/thoughts??

Thanks.

UPDATE: Still an issue, as I need to hit the server to load some data into memory.

Comment: You want to open vcard.aspx each time the button is clicked? why not just define the window.open on the aspx page and wire up the button in the itemtemplate directly?

Comment: Hmmm, well yes, that seems to work. But it's doing a full postback. I've made my repeater an AsyncPostBackTrigger, and put the window.open on the aspx page. The popup now opens, but only after a full page refresh.

Comment: it is probably throwing hidden errors .. use your dev tools to check if you have js errors

Comment: I guess perhaps it seems like it's doing a postback because it's opening a new tab...

Comment: A new tab shouldn't cause a post back of the original page.

Answer (score 1):

Define the js on the page for window opening

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function OpenWin(){

window.open('vCard.aspx',null,'width=50,height=50,top=100,left=100','true');

}

</script>
```

Modify the itemtemplate to point to it.

```
  <ItemTemplate>
                            <!--For IE9 there can be no whitespace -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="140"><strong><%# Eval("DisplayName") %></strong><asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HFname" Value='<%# Eval("SamAccountName") %>'/></td>
                                <td width="100"><%# Eval("Office") %></td>
                                <td width="120"><%# Eval("WorkPhone") %></td>
                                <td width="120"><%# Eval("MobilePhone") %></td>
                                <td width="300" style="text-align: left"><a href="mailto:<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>"><%# Eval("EmailAddress") %></a></td>
                                <td><div class="button"><asp:LinkButton CommandName="vCard" runat="server" ID="lbtnVcard" Text="vCard" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="OpenWin()"/></div></td>
                            </tr>


                        </ItemTemplate>
```

You can now remove the js you wired up to the button just to see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: I knew it was too easy. I need to hit the server on link click in order to load some data into the session. Suggestions?